# Can't SSH from one Digital Ocean droplet to another using Private LAN IP

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vps

I have 2 Digital Ocean instances which have private LAN IP's. The first is 10.130.30.82 and the second is 10.130.35.154. I can ping the second from the first but not SSH. I have copied my keys to both servers using ssh-copy-id and have not altered sshd_config on the second server. My local machine and both servers are ubuntu,

SSH into the second from the first gives this error:

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 11: Bad configuration option: hostkey
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 12: Bad configuration option: hostkey
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 13: Bad configuration option: hostkey
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 15: Bad configuration option: useprivilegeseparation
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 18: Bad configuration option: keyregenerationinterval
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 19: Bad configuration option: serverkeybits
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 22: Bad configuration option: syslogfacility
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 26: Bad configuration option: logingracetime
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 27: Bad configuration option: permitrootlogin
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 28: Bad configuration option: strictmodes
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 35: Bad configuration option: ignorerhosts
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 44: Bad configuration option: permitemptypasswords
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 63: Bad configuration option: x11forwarding
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 64: Bad configuration option: x11displayoffset
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 65: Bad configuration option: printmotd
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 66: Bad configuration option: printlastlog
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 74: Bad configuration option: acceptenv
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 76: Bad configuration option: subsystem
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 87: Bad configuration option: usepam
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 19 bad configuration options
```

Comment: It looks as if the file /etc/ssh/ssh_config is not syntactically correct. Fix that.

Comment: I do not think that this probelm is in any way unclear. It seems that there is an overly "protective" moderator attitude at work here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have altered `ssh_config` with options that should only be used in `sshd_config` (mind the `d`).

The file it keeps complaining about is the configuration for the SSH client and seems to be originating from the source server not the target server.